# How to find a mid point of an android textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a sub-class of TextView and want to draw a horizontal line by making its height to be 1px. It is ok but i also want to make it center vertically by setting the top margin as half of the height.
However it turns out to be failed.
Any solution to it?
thank you

```
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        int h = getHeight();
        lp.setMargins(0, h/2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Basically if you just want to draw an horizontal line, why not doing it in your xml ?

Comment: @A.Omar can you show him , how to do it via xml  with any code ?

Comment: If you are going for a strikethrough effect, consider using `StrikethroughSpan`.

Comment: thanks, but i actually have a reusable textview sub-class. therefore i don't want to do it in xml. I am using api level 11

Comment: lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; solves it. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!.\nA second line test."/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you come here with some screenshots what you want to do , i can help you easily. But i can suggest you to use `FrameLayout` :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#123456" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Horizontal Line" />

</FrameLayout>
```

There is one guide for `FrameLayout` here : [Frame Layout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

And the screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without XML you could override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` and draw the line in your subclassed TextView like so:

```
public final class TextViewEx extends TextView
{
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    protected final void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        float y = getHeight() / 2f;

        canvas.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y, mPaint);
    }
}
```